# path para un engine no es reconocido

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

Necesito su apoyo para verificar esta situación estoy siguiendo la  documentación, para hacer un  `engine` con `rubyOnRails` y quiero probar la gema como dice la documentación.

Agrego en el archivo que llamara al engine:

```
gem 'blorgh', path: 'engines/blorgh'
```

Y sale lo siguiente en la terminal :

> machan@Lenovo:~/Documentos/Ruby/muestra_engine/unicorn$ bundle install
>   The path `/home/machan/Documentos/Ruby/muestra_engine/unicorn/engines/blorgh` does not exist.

alguna idea de cual es mi error?.

agradeceré mucho su ayuda.

Comment: ¿pero es efectivamente `/home/machan/Documentos/Ruby/muestra_engine/unicorn/engines/blorgh` donde tienes tu engine? sino, tienes que poner la ruta donde se encuentra actualmente

Comment: Hola.tengo el engine en una misma carpeta que el ruby ya trate de ingresar la ruta como " gem 'blorgh', path: '/Documentos/Ruby/muestra_engine/unicorn/engines/blorgh'  " , y me sigue  mandando el mismo error que la ruta no esta definida.

Comment: Pero entonces si tienes `gem 'blorgh', path: '/Documentos/Ruby/muestra_engine/unicorn/engines/blorgh'` está mal porque ahí estás indicando que la carpeta documentos está en la carpeta raíz de tu sistema cuando está en tu home. Prueba con `gem 'blorgh', path: '~/Documentos/Ruby/muestra_engine/unicorn/engines/blorgh'` o `gem 'blorgh', path: '/home/machan/Documentos/Ruby/muestra_engine/unicorn/engines/blorgh'`

Comment: Uffff ingresé la respuesta desde mi movil y cambió algunos caracteres. Me refiero a que ingreses `gem 'blorgh', path: '~/Documentos/Ruby/muestra_eng‌​ine/unicorn/engines/blorgh'` o `gem 'blorgh', path: '/home/machan/Documentos/Ruby/muestra_eng‌​ine/unicorn/engines/blorgh'`, cualquiera de las dos debería funcionar

Comment: No entiendo por que los cambia, me rindo. `&‌​#47;` = `/`

Comment: Gracias lo verificare.